# Calculating gradient boosted regressor value from individual decision trees

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm trying to calculate the value of a GBR using its individual decision trees. I thought it would be as simple as predicting on each individual tree and scaling by the learning rate and summing the results but I am not getting the same value when I predict directly through the GBR and I'm wondering if there's some gap in my understanding of how the GBR prediction is calculated (I've even tried digging into sklearns code and it seems to be doing the same thing I'm aiming for).

In short my code looks as follows:

```
gbr = GradientBoostingRegressor(
    max_depth=3,
    learning_rate=0.1,
    n_estimators=50  # number of trees
)

gbr.fit(X,y)  # X is a dataframe which is why you'll see me converting it to numpy and reshaping later

X_sample = X.iloc[0]
X_sample = np.array(X_sample).reshape(1,-1)

print(gbr.predict(X_sample)[0])  # 555315.2295879041

# confirm value of GBR
out_sum = 0
for t in range(50):
    estimator = gbr.estimators_[t,0]  # this is a regressor so there is only one output hence the 0
    value_in_decision_tree = estimator.predict(X_sample)[0]
    out_sum += .1*value_in_decision_tree  # 0.1 = learning rate
print(out_sum)  # 15227.087821374536
```

If it's relevant, the data I'm using the [HSKC dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction). But I'm sure I'm just misunderstanding something about the calculation here so I'm hoping someone can help me out

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. I believe GBR learn the residuals from a base prediction as determined by the loss function so both values I calculated above are correct and `out_sum` corresponds to the predicted residual value. The raw initial prediction in this case was 540088.14176653 as determined by the following:

```
print(gbr.loss_.get_init_raw_predictions(
                X_sample, 
                gbr.init_).astype(np.float64))
```

I copied this from the `_raw_predict_init` method of the `BaseGradientBoosting` [class](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf3/sklearn/ensemble/_gb.py#L1282).